# Plug-in "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard" was unable to instantiate class

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have installed STS-4 in my machine . At beginning it was working fine but after some plugin installation i am not able to "import Spring Getting Started Project" . I am facing below exception

> The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in
>   "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard" was unable to
>   instantiate class
>   "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard.guides.GSImportWizard".
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: can you take a look at the Error Log view to see if that reveals more details? Usually there should be, for example, a complete stack trace for the error, which might help to identify the underlying issue. In addition to that you can always go back in your install history (via the About dialog, configuration details) to see which third-party install caused the problem.

Comment: I am getting blank in Error Log. I observe it is throwing exception only when i install JBOSS server tool in STS 4 .

Comment: In case you can describe a few steps to reproduce this issue starting from a vanilla STS4 installation, you might want to file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues, so that we can investigate this in more detail.

Comment: Thank @MartinLippert , Its will be great help for me .